# Group Microsoft SQL Server to get the time a person holding a case

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

Currently we have this in the database:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evWql.png]

We would like to group the start time and end time for each interval the agent handling the same interaction id.

Expected result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhS1A.png]

Start time using min and End time using max only within the interval the agent handling.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Images of data don't help us help you. Take the time to post it in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statements, but at least well formatted tabular `text`. This, however, looks like a gaps and island problem; if you search the term you may well find the solution.

Comment: Sorry this is the first time i posted a question.
I will try to remove this a repost again

Comment: Don't repost. There's an [edit] feature for a reason.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.